# Visual Studio Code cannot find my source code on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I created my hello world cpp as below in the path c:\cpp\helloworld

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World " << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling is OK with task.json using installed gcc compiler from cygwin under path c:\cygwin64\bin

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler: C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\g++.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i try to debug with following launch.json, the debugger can launch the main.exe. But the debugger cannot locate my source code main.cpp thouth it is directly next to the main.exe.
The error message is "The editor could not be opened because the file was not found." and the editor points to the file "c:\cpp\helloworld\C"

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\main.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": true,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "miDebuggerPath": "c:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                },
                {
                    "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                    "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: what if you name your file `helloworld.cpp`?

Comment: Nothing changed after renaming to "helloworld.cpp". Compile is fine and generates helloworld.exe. Launching started, still cannot find the source file and complaining no file "c:\cpp\helloworld\C"